# R calculated gamma distribution density wrong?

Tags: r, numeric, gamma-distribution

I am trying to numerically calculate marginal likelihood (marginalize over a positive parameter). I am using Gamma distribution as prior for that parameter. Here I looked at the behavior of Gamma distribution for two specific parameter settings:

```
s = 28.4; r = 17000
plot(x, dgamma(x, shape=s, rate = r), type = 'l', ylab = 'density')
abline(v = s/r, col = 'red')
```

I got the following results:

[image: density plot1]

Then I tried the following to get a tighter Gamma distribution:

```
lines(x, dgamma(x, shape=s*1000, rate = r*1000), col = 'blue')
```

and the result:

[image: density plot2]

I am confused. As distribution gets tighter, the height should grow taller, otherwise the area won't integrate to 1. Did I miss anything? Or is there any numerally problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x` variable needs to have more samples to capture the narrow peak in the second density function:

```
x = seq(0, .01, .000001)
s = 28.4; r = 17000
plot(x, dgamma(x, shape=s, rate = r), type = 'l', ylab = 'density')
abline(v = s/r, col = 'red')
lines(x, dgamma(x, shape=s*1000, rate = r*1000), col = 'blue')
```

[image]